# CSS min-height in percents won't work if container has min-height in percents too

Tags: html, css

I have a simple markup here:

```
<div class="fixh">

    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            inner
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I want to make inner block to have at least 100% height of outer block. If content is bigger than 100%, it should overflow. But inner block with min-height:100% won't work!
Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/5378/

Comment: Why you don't just add `height: 100%;` to element with class `.outer`?

Comment: If content is bigger than 100%, it should have inner scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min-height` doesn't actually work as well with percentages. What would fix this is just using `height:100%` here:

```css
.fixh {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
}

.outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixh">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            inner
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You should always specify the `height` and `width` styles when using the `min-height` or `min-width` styles, respectively (or `max-height` and `max-width` for that matter). Otherwise the CSS doesn't know it needs to change, so it won't.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you asked.

http://jsfiddle.net/w9Lghbuw/1/

```
.fixh {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
}
.outer {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}
.inner {
    color:#fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 20px;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: So I can't use min-height that way I tried, ok then